# Integration of subdifferential.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, multivalued-functions

For example, for the function
$$
f(x)=|x|,\quad\text{$-1\le x\le1$,}
$$
the subdifferential $D^{+}f(x)$ is
$$
D^{+}f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1\quad&\text{for $x\in[-1,0)$,}\\
[-1,1]\quad&\text{at $x=0$,}\\
1\quad&\text{for $x\in(0,1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$

I now want to know what the the following integral is: (formally)
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}D^{+}f(x)dx=?.
$$
However, as you see, $D^{+}f$ is multi-valued function.
I thought that it is alright to interpret this integral as Lebersgue integral since we may ignore the point $x=0$, that is,
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}D^{+}f(x)dx=-1\cdot|[-1,0)|+1\cdot|(0,1]|=0,
$$
but **what happend if we interpret in the sense of Riemann integral?
Can we interpret in this sense in the first place?**
I have searched but I didn't find any information.

Please give me some comments for my question and my interpretation in the sense of Lebesgue integral if you know.

Answer (score 4):

Source:  **Proposition 1.6.1** from *Convex functions and their applications: a contemporary approach* by Niculescu and Persson.

Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous convex function and let $\varphi:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\varphi(x)\in\partial f(x)$ for every $x\in\operatorname{int} I$. Then for every $a<b$ in $I$ we have 
  $$ f(b)-f(a)=\int^b_a\varphi(t)dt.$$

Comment: Does such a result where $I$ is replaced by a Hilbert space?